# Why are my Views resetting their position, when keyboard is opened?

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

My task is to attach a textfield to the top of the Keyboard. When the keyboard moves up the textfield should move up with it. But that is not working..

//EDIT: If I close the keyboard (with return key) the textfield instantly positions on top of the keyboard and moves down perfectly with it.

here is my code:

```
    func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
         let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
         let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size

         var messageFrame:CGRect = self.textField.frame
         messageFrame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {self.textField.frame = messageFrame})

}

func keyboardWillDisappear(notification: NSNotification){
         let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
         let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size

         var messageFrame:CGRect = self.textField.frame
         messageFrame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {self.textField.frame = messageFrame})

}
```

Comment: "not working" means? Provide a screenshot or more details.

Comment: It does a Strange 'Jump' animation. Look at the other comments for further reference

Answer (score 0):

Use a standard code for such things:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
   textField.inputAccessoryView = CustomView;
   return YES;
}
```

Where CustomView - is UITextField

Comment: That is propably the best way to attach it to Keyboard. But my goal is a behavior same like in the messages App or whatsapp, where the Text Field is always visible at the bottom of the screen and the tableView(the Chat bubbles) move up or down accordingly (even when pulling down the table view)

Comment: You can try to use this vendor - this is one of the best solutions for messaging apps. https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController

Answer (score 0):

I have made some changes in your code

```
func keyboardWillAppear(notification: NSNotification){
         let userInfo:NSDictionary = notification.userInfo!
         let keyboardSize:CGSize = userInfo.objectForKey(UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey)!.CGRectValue.size

         CGFloat newY = self.textField.frame.origin.y - keyboardSize.height;
         UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
             self.textField.frame = CGRectMake(self.textField.frame.origin.x, newY , self.textField.frame.size.width, self.textField.frame.size.height);
})

}
```

Comment: Mh this doesn't seem to work.. I think there is s Problem with the text Labels Position when opening Keyboard. I tried to animate it up by a hardcoded value in ViewDidAppear() method and it works perfectly, but if i copy the code in the keyboardWillAppear() or textFieldDidStartEditing() the Text Field does either nothing or a quick Jump back to its original position. I am using Auto Layout btw.